# Migrate Ax2012 R3 CU12 model to Dynamics 365 error: no metadata to upgrade

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-365-operations

I’m upgrading a custom product/model from AX2012 R3 CU12 to  Dynamics365 using the Lifecycle Services code upgrade service.
At the point where uploading the compressed model store, I hit the following error:
“Customer models contain no metadata to upgrade. Please make sure the Descriptor folder has valid contents.”

I’ve tried searching online for more information or an explanation of the error, but I can’t find a solution.

Comment: Same question in Dynamics Community: [Customer models contain no metadata to upgrade](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/236339)

Comment: Yes, that was me too.

Comment: Try following this http://bluefort.com.mt/dynamics-365-for-operations-code-upgrade-steps-from-dynamics-ax-2012/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported the model store again from AX2012 R3 CU12 and uploaded the new (compressed) file.  The process completed successfully, so I assume there must have gone something wrong with the first export of the model store.